# How to pick python 3.11 as a conda environment in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, python-3.11

I am just start using vscode to write python code. And I am normally using conda as my package and environment tool.

I am trying to create a conda environment for python 3.11 in my project directory based on the instruction in the vscode official document https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments.

However, it only list python 3.7 - 3.10 as the python version I could choose.

I am wondering how could I pick python 3.11 in the conda environment?

I am using an Intel 2019 macbook pro. I already installed python3.11 through homebrew from command line.
And I have also installed miniconda and created a python 3.11 environment through command line.
However, when I tried to create .conda environment in vscode

[Screenshot to create python environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n5uj.png)

[Screenshot to select python interpreter version for conda environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3StYq.png)

It only show python 3.7 - 3.10

Comment: Have you tried ```ctrl shift P``` and select interpreter?

Answer (score 12):

This problem is related to *conda*, but it's not a vscode problem. You can create a conda environment with the following command,

```
conda create --name myenv -c conda-forge python=3.11
```

Then select the created conda interpreter in the **Select Interpreter** panel.

[image]

More information on [conda commands](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-python).

Answer (score 6):

The 17th of April 2023, the support for python 3.11 was added to conda [(see issue in the official repo)](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11170)

You should now be able to download conda directly using:

```
conda create -n my_conda_env_with_py311 python=3.11
```

Vs code should soon (if not already) allow you to pick python 3.11 in their GUI for you conda env !

Comment: That works only if you don't use anaconda such as conda create -n my_conda_env_with_py311 python=3.11 anaconda

Comment: @gench, I am not sure to understand your comment, could you elaborate ?

Comment: This doesnt work: "conda create -n my_conda_env_with_py311 python=3.11 anaconda"

Comment: @gench Oh okay. Well I do not include anaconda in the command usually, so I do not really know how to fix your issue sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.11 is now available through the "standard" channels

```
conda create -p ./.venv python=3.11
```

**Old Answer**

Right now, python 3.11 is still quite new so it's not yet available through the "standard" channels. You should still be able to install it with `conda` from the command line:

```
conda create -c conda-forge -p ./.venv python=3.11
```

`-c`: Adds the "conda-forge" channel: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python

`-p`: Creates the virtial environment to the given path

Comment: Why are you using a `--prefix` and a hidden folder at that? That's just unnecessary confusion for users.

Comment: @merv I understood from OPs first screenshot he wants to create the conda environment in the workspace directory in that folder. Naming the folder differently or using `--name` instead works just as well if that's more to your liking.